# Regarding null check plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Please advise for such plugin that can help me in my code that where I forgot to implement the null check, is there any such plugin exists so that I can install in my eclipse

Comment: do you mean a plugin that performs static code analysis?  You should look at FindBugs and PMD.  They both offer configurable checks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try changing your eclipse configuration first rather than using a plugin. Try setting *Windows > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Potential Programming Problems > Potential Null Pointer Access* to anything besides ignore.

As a side note, always try to use a defensive programming approach if you feel like the code you're writing has many potential exception/error courses.

Comment: I don't see this as an option

Answer (score 0):

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/ is what you're looking for. FindBugs is a static source code analysis tool which can find many common programming errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the nullpointer exception is the best null check. You should always test every method/function with jUnit and then you see wether there are some null errors.